# Find for what $n$ and for what field $K$ exists $A \in GL_n(K)$ with order $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, finite-groups, minimal-polynomials

Find conditions on $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $K$ field such that exists $A \in GL_n(K)$ with order $n+1$. Specify $A$. Explain why the same argument wouldn't work without those conditions.

This is what I've done

A matrix $A$ with order $n+1$ must have a minimal polynomial that divides $x^{n+1}-1=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\dots+x+1)$, since $A^{n+1}=I\implies (x^{n+1}-1)A=0$ We now consider $A$ as the matrix representation of $q:=x^n+x^{n-1}\dots+x+1$. This is

$$A=M(q)=\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
0 & \cdots & 0
\end{matrix}\\
\\
I_{n-1}
\end{matrix} &
\begin{matrix}
-1 \\ \vdots \\ -1
\end{matrix}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, $A$ has $q$ as it minimal polynomial and its order divides $n+1$ since $(x^{n+1}-1)A=(x-1)qA=0$. Now, I can check that $A^ke_1\neq e_1 \;\forall\,k<n+1$ so its order should be $n+1$. Now I have to prove that $M(q)\in GL_n(K)$ but that's trivial since $-1\neq 0$ ($K\neq\{0\}$) so $\text{det}A=\pm 1$. I think this should complete the proof but a hint in the exercise says that we have to impose conditions on $n$ and $\text{char}K$.

Comment: Check that $A^ke_1\neq e_1$ for $k<n+1$ by direct computation, where $e_1$ means the first standard basis vector.

Comment: You say that the minimal polynomial "must be" $(x^{n+1}-1)/(x-1)$. That's not true. There are matrices in $GL_5(\mathbb{Q})$ of order $6=5+1$ whose minimal polynomial is $(x^2-x+1)(x-1)$, which doesn't even divide $(x^{5+1}-1)/(x-1)$.

Comment: There must be something amiss with the opening sentence; if its all about finding _some_ $n$, $K$ and $A$, then take $n=1$, $K=\Bbb Q$, and  $A=\pmatrix{-1}$ and you're done. If it is about finding _all possible_ combinations of $n$, $K$ and $A$, then this may be quite a lot of work. Your before-last sentence suggests that you want to find $n$, $K$ such that _there does not exist_ any such $A$, which is a more reasonable task (and you can find an easy example with $n=1$), but "specify $A$" is then of course not possible. But please be clear about what the question actually is.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you, it seems right

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, you're right, I edited the post, I just wanted to use $M(q)$

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen You're right, he exercise is quite imprecise, now I have tried to explain it clearer

Comment: Your "proof" that $A=M(q)$ is order dividing $n+1$ is flawed: "$(x^{n+1}-1)A$" makes no sense. The proof would be better so: $A$ has characteristic polynomial $q(x)$ by direct calculation, and so $q(A)=0$ by Cayley-Hamilton; and so $A^{n+1}-I=(A-I)q(A)=0$. So unless I am missing something you have given an example of an element of order $n+1$ in every $GL_{n}(K)$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Basically, since $A$ has minimal polynomial $q$, we have $A^n+A^{n-1}+\cdots + A+I=0$. So $A^{n+1}-I=(A-I)(A^n+\cdots+A+I)=(A-I)0=0\implies A^{n+1}=I$. $(x^{n+1}-1)A$ is just the product of the $K[X]$-module structure of $GL_n(K)$.

Comment: @Juan You are now going round in circles. In the question you say you are proving the min poly is $q$ and in your comment you're using the fact the mp is $q$. And you don't mean the $K[X]$-module structure of $GL_n(K)$m because $GL_n(K)$ isn't a module. But enough, one way or another the underlying question is answered.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry, the $K[X]$-module is $K^n$, but $A$ represents an endomorphism so the reasoning is valid, although you are right it is ambiguous to use that notation for matrices. In my proof I suppose that is known that the mp of any $M(p)$ is $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given an example, for any integer $n>0$ and field $K$, of a matrix $A\in\mathbf{GL}_n(K)$ with minimal polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^nX^i=X^n+\cdots+X+1$. Since that polynomial divides $X^{n+1}-1$, one has $A^{n+1}=I$. Also, it being the *minimal* polynomial implies that $A^0=I,A^1,\ldots,A^{n-1}$ are linearly independent, and in particular distinct, so the order of $A$ is not less than $n$. If $n\geq2$ this implies that the order of $A$ is $n+1$ (since it must divide $n+1$). If $n=1$ you have the matrix $A=\pmatrix{-1}$ and the only remaining question is can this have order $n=1$? Indeed it can, if and only of $K$ is of characteristic$~2$. And for that case the question is does the field $K$ itself contain any elements of multiplicative order$~2$, and here the answer is "no" in all cases, since $X^2-1=(X-1)^2$ in characteristic$~2$, so the only solution to $x^2=1$ is $x=1$ which has order$~1$.

So the answer to the question is: such $A$ exists *unless* $n=1$ and $K$ is of characteristic$~2$, and if so your matrix $A$ is an example. (The only remaining case, to be pedantically exhaustive, is $n=0$, where the unique $0\times0$ matrix, the identity in dimension$~0$, is indeed of order $n+1=1$.)